# Modules not saving in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-extensions

The problem exists with MetaMod (and Jumi). When I make changes to a module and hit save I get kicked to the Module Manager (just as if I hit Save and Quit). The module then has the 'Checked Out' padlock next to it and when I go back into the module the changes made have not been saved. When I 'Check In' the module and go back into look, the changes have still not been saved.

I have recently moved the Joomla site using Akeeba and this is the only issue I seem to have. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I've not been able to find and solutions yet.

If I use simple code such as

```
    $user =& JFactory::getUser();
    $userID = $user->id;

if ($userID !== 0){
 return 186;
}
```

Then it will save fine. As soon as I add a query it breaks.

```
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
$userID = $user->id;
$query = "SELECT id FROM schools WHERE leader_id='{$userID}'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$amIanRL = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($amIanRL !== 0){
 return 186;
}
```

Incidentally the code above works on a number of modules that I created before the Akeeba restore (they just return different modules).

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following query:

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$userID = $user->id;
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('*')
->from('#__schools')
->where('leader_id = ' . $userID . );
$db->setQuery($query);

$results = $db->loadObjectList();
if ($results !== 0){
  return 186;
}
```

It has a few tweaks and sticks to the Joomla 2.5 coding standards.

Comment: Thanks for this. This gets saved but didn't return 186. I've managed to find the exact word where it was breaking (by saving it line by line then word by word) Apparently the schools needed to be enclosed in inverted commas, 'schools'. I don't know why this is the case on the live site and not my localhost though :(